# Core Data Arrays are empty after a while

Tags: iphone, ios, arrays, core-data, memory-management

Maybe I don't  understand something about memory management in Core Data.
I have succeeded to fetch an array of entities.
I saved this array with Retain.
After that, I see that this array I retained is empty.
It has a memory address, but no objects (When I retained it, it had objects).
Can someone please help me solve this mystery?

Avi

Answer (score 0):

There's a few possibilities.

(1) You're not storing an array, you're storing a mutable array (though you don't know it!) and someone else is changing it's contents. Instead of `retain`, try `copy`.

(2) You're accidentally changing the array that you're pointing to. You can find this out by setting a breakpoint on the line that stores your array and seeing how many times it gets triggered.

You should definitely do (1) even if it doesn't fix your bug. Anything that has a mutable subclass (i.e. NSArray has NSMutableArray, NSSet has NSMutableSet etc.) should be `copy` not `retain`

Comment: Hi, thanks. Changed it to NSArray. Still no help... Now I see I was wrong. The Array is nil after a while... don't know why. Very strange...

Comment: wait - is the array 'nil' or is the array empty?

Answer (score 0):

Before storing into array always allocate that array. And if you are making an array inside an block it might not be accessible out side the block.
in interface:
NSMutableArray *commonAry;

in implementation:
commonAry=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];//allocating the coomon array 
now you can add fetched object from into the array.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. Turned out I had a retained property that was READONLY, and I was setting the internal member and not retaining it in the init method. I was however still freeing it on the dealloc method (as I always do with retained properties).
So just check your retains and releases are always matching up as it sounds like it is being released too much.